# Regular Expression for Integer greater than 0 and less than 11

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to modify this Regex so that you get numbers greater or equals 1 or less than or equals to 10. This Regex allows >= 0 or <= 10.

I have a text field on a form that takes numbers equals or greater than 0 and less than 11. I could use IF's and logical operators, TryParse but I kinda like the Regex.

```
@"^\d$|^[1][0]$"
```

Comment: Why are you using a regex for this?

Comment: Why RegEx for ints? Supposing you have a number in a string (that's the type regexes are meant for), you can cast the string in to an integer

Comment: I have added the reasoning to my original question. Thank you!

Comment: Are you seriously intending to use RegEx for this? Please don't. Your friends might laugh at you.

Comment: So easy and so much faster though: `int result; if (!int.TryParse(myStr, out result) || result < 1 || result > 10) { /* error */ }`

Comment: Again I mentioned I am learning, I am not writing a program for Los-Alamos Nuclear Arsenal. Just practice projects.

Comment: Don't want to be too pushy, but if you're learning, take the advice everyone is giving!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to modify your regex only a little bit

```
@"^[1-9]$|^10$"
```

You don't need the square brackets around single characters and I would use a group around the alternation and change it to

```
@"^([1-9]|10)$"
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32t3r)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is this is not something for which you should use regex.  If anything you would use regular expressions to parse out the numbers and then compare them with standard `if (num >= 0)` etc.

```
// EDIT: replaced regex with this:
int number;
if (Int32.TryParse(myString, out number)) {
    // do something, like:
    if (number >= 0 || number <= 10) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Completely makes sense but my goal is to learn other ways to do things, and as you recommended, I could have used TryParse and some operators but I wanted to see how I can assigned Boolean and use the Regix. - Thanks!

Comment: @UnaverageGuy I see.  Yeah I know what you mean, it's always fun to learn new ways of doing things!

Comment: This RegEx ain't even right. It matches numbers between `0` and `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: @Abbondanza that's the point!  The point is the get the number _out_ and _then_ compare it..

Comment: @mmmshuddup This makes even less sense than using a RegEx in the first place.

Comment: @Abbondanza It does make sense and I disagree; nevertheless, I've updated my answer.  Thanks for your feedback anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using WinForms, then `NumericUpDown` control with `MinValue` equal to `1` and `MaxValue` equal to 10 will do the job. Also you don't need parsing - property `Value` will contain your value (well, it will be of type `decimal` - just cast it to `int`).

Another reason for using `NumericUpDown` - it does not allow to input anything except digits, and up-down arrows are saying to user - this control is waiting numbers from you.

Comment: That is true but look at all the advice I would have missed? Sometimes the easiest way teaches you very little. Thanks everyone, All the answers were valuable!

Answer (score 3):

While I recommend simply using logical operators to check if an int is between 1 and 10, here's a working regex:

```
^(10|[1-9])$
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
^(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10)$
```

Very explicit, can't misinterpret, clear as day.  Makes for a better regex for me.  Short and cryptic isn't necessary here

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
^([1-9]|10)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex to check number from 1 to 10 -

**^([1-9]|10)$**